# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects in Flask with MySQL

Tags: python, sql, flask

I make python code work with MySQL and Flask.

If a user input a location name and radius in web, python code search the information about the location and others location that within the radius in MySQL.

Here is my code

'names' is location name entered by the user.

'ron' is the radius entered by the user.

```
 @app.route('/index', methods=["GET","POST"])
 def search_location(names, ron):
    row2=[]
    dis=ron/100
    cur = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from map_info where loc_name = '"+names+"'")
    info_db = cur.fetchall()

    cur.execute("select mapY, mapX from map_info where loc_name = '"+names+"'")
         for row in cur:
             print row
    row2.append(float(row[0]))
    row2.append(float(row[1]))
    row2.append(int(dis))

    cur.execute("select loc_name, mapY, mapX ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians("+row2[0]+ ") * cos( radians( mapY ) ) * cos( radians( mapX )- radians("+row2[1]+"))+ sin( radians("+row2[0]+") ) * sin( radians( mapY ) ) ) ) as distance FROM map_info HAVING distance < "+row2[2])

return render_template('index.html', results=info_db, rons=ron)
```

But 'TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects' is occurs in the last SQL statement that search the location within radius.

How can I fix it?

I would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row2[]` is `Float` but you are trying to concatenate it with a `String`. Python has a strict type checking (no implicit type conversions). Solution is to change `row2[index]` to string. Try this:-

```
cur.execute("select loc_name, mapY, mapX ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians("+str(row2[0])+ ") * cos( radians( mapY ) ) * cos( radians( mapX )- radians("+str(row2[1])+"))+ sin( radians("+str(row2[0])+") ) * sin( radians( mapY ) ) ) ) as distance FROM map_info HAVING distance < "+str(row2[2]))
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to help. If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept as the solution.